# Updating few fields using FormField

Tags: django, django-forms

Should I have to have separate ModelForm for Save and Update? Because in Update screen I want to hide/show some of the filed from Entry screen.

Comment: That is better option.

Comment: another way can be of setting the fields of the form when you initialize it. but it may be too complex.